# Unable to cancel IBM Cloud virtual server

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm attempting to cancel a virtual server, but the button 'Cancel Device' is disabled:

[image]

How can I cancel my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this was a temporary 'glitch', my second attempt the 'Cancel Device' button was enabled and I was able to cancel the device:

[image]